# ksoap2 consuming .Net service with sessions

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, session, android-ksoap2

GetMessages is a method I have in a .net web service for my chat program. It gets a collection of messages, only sending new ones by saving the last message ID in a session variable.

```
HeaderProperty mSessionHeader = null;

public SoapObject GetMessages()
{
    ...
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.V11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.bodyOut = request;

    HttpTransport transport = new HttpTransport(URL);
    transport.debug = true;

    // Build request header
    LinkedList<HeaderProperties> reqHeaders = new LinkList<HeaderProperties>();

    if (mSessionHeader != null) {
        reqHeaders.add(mSessionHeader); //using the session id from last header
    }

    List<HeaderProperties> respHeaders = transport.call(ACTION, envelope, reqHeaders);

    // See note after code
    for (HeaderProperty hp : respHeaders) {
        if (hp.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie"))
        {
            mSessionHeader = hp;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
}
```

the value of mSessionHeader is something like

> set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0zzfwxxp1sakeafybjzsxp0k; path=/; HttpOnly

However, the GUID part changes every call to ... transport.call()
When I use the same header (by putting if mSessionHeader == null around the for loop)
it still does not work... the method gets every message sent regardless of the
position i set in the Web Service

Do I have to add more headers then just the ASP.NET_SessionId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised there isn't demand for an answer to this... anyways I found it.

The request header to send a cookie is different from the response -

Request

> "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=#####"

Response

> "Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=#####"

So the above line -

```
reqHeaders.add(mSessionHeader);
```

gets changed to

```
reqHeaders.add(new HeaderProperty("Cookie", mSessionHeader.getValue());
```